# How to retrieve object by comparing nested object value to another object value

Tags: c#, linq

I have Object A which has a field DocumentName and another object nested inside it called Object B which has a field called Sku. `I Have a List<ObjectA> and List<ObjectB>` I need to now compare ObjectA.ObjectB.Sku to ObjectB.Sku to retrieve The corresponding Object A. How would I go about doing this in C#? I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
foreach (var item in blockProducts)
            {
                foreach (var block in flyerBlocks)
                {
                    CurrentBlock = (FlyerBlock)block.Products.Where(x => x.Sku.Equals(item.Sku));
                  

                }
}
```

blockProducts represents ListObjectB while flyerBlocks represents ListObjectA. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you elaborate `but it does not work`? Any specific error? Kindly provide sample data with expected output for above case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what I was doing wrong. This is how I solved my issue I did not need the second foreach.

```
foreach (var item in blockProducts)
{
     var CurrentBlock = flyerBlocks
                    .FirstOrDefault(
                    b => b.Products.Any(p => p.Sku == item.Sku)
                   );            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-6.0). `Equals` evaluates whether or not you have one instance. If you want to compare two instances for equality based on the state of the instances you can override `Equals`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nesting linq [`Any()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=net-6.0) as the [`Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=net-6.0) clause. You can then cook something like this:

```
IEnumerable<ObjectA> result =
     flyerBlocks.Where(x =>
          x.Products.Any(y =>
               blockProducts.Any(z => y.Sku.Equals(z.Sku))));
```

Note: this kind of linq can work to some extent on entity framework too